# SQL Server stored procedure is inserting two records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure should clone the item once, but it's creating two cloned records.

My C# program has a button that calls this method. Debugging has it only fire once and returns the 2nd cloned item's neweventid

```
protected void cloneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("addRecycleEventAcceptedMaterialsClone"))
            {
                //object returnValue;

                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_id", qsEventId);
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //returnValue = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                NewEventID = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("eventDetail.aspx?eventid=" + NewEventID);
    }
```

I checked and no duplicate event_id's it is a primary key/ Identity column

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addRecycleEventAcceptedMaterialsClone] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    --Pass in the original event_id
    @event_id int
    --@newEvent_id INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO RECYCLE_EVENT (event_nm, start_dt, end_dt, start_tm, end_tm,
                              website_ad, address_ad, city_nm, state_cd, zip_cd,
                              county_id, description_ds, moreinfo_ds, 
                              latitude, longitude, phone_nr)
     SELECT 
        event_nm, start_dt, end_dt, start_tm, end_tm,
        website_ad, address_ad, city_nm, state_cd, zip_cd,
        county_id,  description_ds, moreinfo_ds,
        latitude, longitude, phone_nr 
    FROM 
        RECYCLE_EVENT
    WHERE
        event_id = @event_id

    --SET @newEvent_id = IDENT_CURRENT('RECYCLE_EVENT');    
    --SELECT @newEvent_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);
    --SELECT @newEvent_id AS newEventID

--NEW CLONED EVENT HAS BEEN ADDED AND A NEW ID (newEventID) has been generated.
--NOW INSERT all materials accepted for the @event_id and insert them into the RECYCLER_EVENT_MATERIALS_ACCEPTED table
--Give it the newEventID

INSERT INTO RECYCLER_EVENT_MATERIALS_ACCEPTED ( 
        event_id,
        material_type_id,
        acceptance_cd,
        residential_fl,
        commercial_fl,
        service_type_cd,
        end_dt,
        event_material_cloned_id
        )
        SELECT 
        IDENT_CURRENT('RECYCLE_EVENT'),
        material_type_id,
        acceptance_cd,
        residential_fl,
        commercial_fl,
        service_type_cd,
        end_dt,
        event_material_id
        FROM RECYCLER_EVENT_MATERIALS_ACCEPTED
        where event_id = @event_id

        --Grab all the records that have the old event_material_id
        --insert a new row using the same county id and the new event_material_id
        --eventid-76: material-id's: 18, 21, 22
        --eventid-124: material-id's: 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33

        INSERT INTO RECYCLER_EVENT_COUNTY_SERVED (
            county_id,
            event_material_id )
            SELECT s.county_id, a.event_material_id
            FROM RECYCLER_EVENT_COUNTY_SERVED s
            INNER JOIN RECYCLER_EVENT_MATERIALS_ACCEPTED a ON s.event_material_id = a.event_material_cloned_id
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing it twice from your code, first via `ExecuteNonQuery` and then via `ExecuteScalar`, so that there is insertion twice rather than once.

Answer (score 0):

you are executing the stored procedure twice,

```
 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 NewEventID = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Both call the insert, I would comment out the first line.

Comment: Thanks bowlturner for your recommendation!